# JavaScript-HTML: Create ComboBox with non-selectable items

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, combobox

I would like to create a ComboBox like you can see in the following image

[image: Combobox]

The Combo/Menu/List should allow some items to be bold (Main Categories), and to have "sub-categories" under each main category. The bold items ***should not*** be clickeable or selectable (I guess these items should have value="") ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look into [optgroup](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp) tag

Answer (score 1):

For the formatting, you might want to try [jListbox: jquery plugin](http://www.senamion.com/blog/2009/08/08/jlistbox-jquery-plugin-for-formatted-select-box/):

[image: jListbox]
<sub>(source: [senamion.com](http://www.senamion.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/jlistbox_screen.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Well, that isn't a combobox (there is no free text component), so all you need to do is include some [optgroup](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTGROUP) elements.